# How to get write 'where' condition using 'am' in mysql.

Tags: mysql

I am storing time in mysql '1467252000'. Now I want write a select query which return me result which include time  of 'am'.

My table  structure is like this

**User table**

> ```
> id  name time_stamp
> 1   uyhj 1467252000
> ```

Comment: Here is the full list of date and time functions https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html checkout `from_unixtime()` and `date_format()`, try and let us know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`FROM_UNIXTIME()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) and [`DATE_FORMAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(time_stamp), '%Y %m %d %h:%i %p') 
FROM UserTable
```

---

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(1467252000)
```

Result:

```
2016 06 30 04:00 AM
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use date_format

```
select date_format(time_stamp, '%b %d %Y %h:%i %p') from my_table
```

if not already a date use from_unixtime too

```
 select date_format(from_unixtime(time_stamp), '%b %d %Y %h:%i %p') from my_table
```

Comment: it is returning me null